# How to call WCF REST service method in a browser

Tags: json, rest, wcf, wcf-endpoint, webhttpbinding

I had created WCF REST service which return JSON format. 
My question was " I am unable to find my Operation Contract method in a browser?"[image]

Below is my Service Contract

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
namespace WcfService1
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

            [OperationContract]
            WcfService1.Service1.Person GetData(string id);

    }


}
```

**Service1.svc.cs**

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfService1
{

    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
      [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
                    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                    UriTemplate = "data/{id}")]
        public Person GetData(string id)
        {
            // lookup person with the requested id 
            return new Person()
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(id),
                Name = "Leo Messi"
            };
        }


        public class Person
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Below was a EndPoint

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:62030/Service1.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <client>
      <endpoint name="JsonService1" address="http://localhost:62030/Service1.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1"></endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had resolved by adding below Fsactory in service1.cs

```
Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"
```

Service1.cs

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfService1.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Json Output:[image]

Answer (score 0):

use localhost:62030/Service1.svc/data/3. You are using wrong URI. Format for calling is  service name with uritemplate in your case  url is localhost:62030/Service1.svc and uritemplate is data/id so cpmplete url is  localhost:62030/Service1.svc/data/3